# PHP synchronize timezone daylight savings issue

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, synchronize

I have a website that loads data into a MySQL table. Two of the entries in the table are 'startdate' and 'enddate'. 'startdate' is automatic using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. 'enddate' is chosen by the user using a date picker.

This creates a problem if the user is in a different timezone than the server. For example (I'm in Pacific timezone, server is in Central). If I create an entry at 5pm and choose an end date of 10pm, it goes into the database as 7pm and 10pm, creating a 3-hour window instead of 5. What I want is to convert the end date to Central time (the same as the server). So, using my example, I would want the entries in the database to be 7pm and 12 midnight.

I can get the users timezone offset with this javascript:

```
var d = new Date();
var timezone = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

This returns -7 (I'm in GMT-8, I'm assuming the 1-hour dif is because of daylight savings). My first thought for a solution is to assume the server is in -5, and compare the two (going back to my example, -5 - -7 = 2, so add 2 to the 'enddate').

The problem comes when we switch back to standard time. I assume that my javascript will start to return -8 instead of -7, breaking my function. I know about PHP's date_default_timezone_get(), but that returns a string instead of a number. I guess what I need is a similar function that would (for Central time) return -5 during daylight savings and -6 during standard time.

Comment: Can't you obtain all relevant dates in UTC?

Comment: If you're using mysql `timestamp` field - then everything should be ok. Just specify the correct client's timezone in the begin of the mysql session.

Comment: I'm using timestamp only for 'startdate' which is always central time. 'enddate' comes from a date picker, which is based on the user's local time. I need a way to convert the user's local time to central time.

Comment: @zerkms I wan't all the dates in the database to be central time. In other words, I need to convert user's local time to central time, not the other way around.

Comment: @user617123: you don't need to want that. Timezone is a presentational thing only. So store it in `timestamp` and convert to particular timezone on output step

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks! I wasn't sure what you meant at first. I used MySQL's UTC_TIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Then I use my Javascript function to convert the 'enddate' to UTC also. Now every entry in the database is homogenous. Perfect.

Comment: @zerkms: Maybe I'm missing something, but I was thinking if I specify the client's timezone in MySQL and then use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, different entries from different users would be based on different times. For example, two users might create an entry at the same time but one would say 2pm and the other would say 3pm because they were in different timezones. I wanted everything to be homogenous.

Comment: @user617123: no, mysql stores `timestamp` field values in UTC and convert from/to user's timezone. So doesn't matter what is user's local time - if you have specified correct user's timezone - you'll have valid UTC time stored in the field.

Comment: @zerkms: Hmmm... I tried your method. I tried to set both 'startdate' and 'enddate' to the current time. I used:

Comment: ...`set time_zone = '-7:00'; insert into mydb.mytable ('startdate', 'enddate') values (current_timestamp, '2011-08-31 11:48:00);` and the entries in the database ended up being 13:48:15 and 11:48:00. They don't match up.

Comment: @user617123: you made a mistake somewhere then. That method works.

Answer (score 2):

Use a mysql timestamp field.

Or save all the data in UTC, and then do what needs to be done after in php.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL's UTC_TIMESTAMP instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, converts 'startdate' to UTC time. My javascript code:

```
var d = new Date();
var timezone = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

Can be used to convert 'enddate' to UTC time. Now everything is in UTC and it matches up.